# rigging lag problem

Tags: rigging

It's lagging when I try to rig it. But some projects don't get lag and some projects get lag. There are about 200,000 verts and 200,000 faces for stuttering projects.[my stuttering project](https://cafeattach.naver.net/9e0b8234221514a2856c0e3d07ef9be44416e83f/20200524_200_cafefile/30035139_1590312059900_XWP07m_blend/hime%2520hina.blend?type=attachment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object has 207,000 vertices, but the laces and eyelets only have 130,000, which seems a bit incoherent (also there's a kind of glitch on the mesh when your armature is in Pose mode, I don't know why?).

You should lower down this number: Begin by using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Un-Subdivide*.

[image]

Then select an edge ring, go the *Select* menu > *Checker Deselect*, in the *Operator* box choose for example *Skip* > 3, then *Select* > *Select Loops* > *Edge Loops*, then X to *Dissolve Edges*. Same thing for the laces vertical edges and for the eyelets...

[image]

Comment: thank you so much :)